# edit box text won't selected when clicked using ajax and jQuery on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, cross-browser

Whenever I click on an edit box , the input field(text) will not stay selected or  it is not setting focus back in that input field.

Please note this editbox is in a table,but this works fine in google chrome the issue in Firefox.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.edit').click(function () {
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="' + $(this).text().length + '" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        $('#editbox').focus();
    });
    $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "supplierprice/config.php",
                data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
}); 


</script>
```

My Html

```
<table id="sorting" class="tablesorter" style="width: 100px; table-layout: fixed;" >

<thead>
<tr>
<th>6xxA <span>  <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture2.png" style="margin:-62px -21px -9px 17px"></span>
<th>6xxB <span>  <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture2.png" style="margin:-62px -21px -9px 21px"></span>
</th>
<th  >10xx <span> <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture2.png" style="margin:-62px -21px -9px 32px"></span>
</th>
<th >11xx <span> <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture2.png" style="margin:-62px -21px -9px 32px"></span>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody >
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'fms';
$dbPassword = 'xxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplierprice");


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo '  <td class="edit region '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>
        <td class="edit country '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td class="edit networkname '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
            <td class="edit mcc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>    
            <td class="edit mnc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
            <td class="edit mnp '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>


        </tr>';


}

?>


</td>


</tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: Post your HTML or better make a fiddle of it .

Comment: Use the deferred syntax of on (with a selector), attached to the document or body, rather than use `live`.

Comment: `#editbox`--> The HTML you posted does not have any ID like that.

Comment: You have an erroneous `</td>` before `</tbody>`

Comment: I did not find a lot of connection between your HTM and JS, so i fiddled the same with my mark up and your js code : http://jsfiddle.net/5XhvJ/  . I tested it in FF and it works !

Also you are not ending the first `th` And you do not need the last `td`.

Comment: @ The Dark Knight i have id did you see this  $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="' + $(this).text().length + '" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        $('#editbox').focus();and i already have an value in edit box i want to focus on that value in editbox

Comment: @The Dark Knight i tried but its not working i taken this code from iwebux.com/demos/ajax please open this in firefox and try to open the last column then you understand what the issue is thanks –

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td.edit').click(function() {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="' + $(this).text().length + '" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

        //Id must be unique, assuming only one element with id="editbox" exixts
        $('#editbox').focus();

        //return false
        return false;

    });
```

Note: please make sure html structure is correct and Id (editbox) is unique :)